# Segmented Controller on Popover Exit Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a segmented controller (two segments) that resides on a popover.  My prepareForSeque method works fine, returning the correct default selectedSegmentIndex. But when I select the other segment and exit the popover, my app crashes when it executes the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method, as seen in the code fragment below.

What am I doing wrong? I want the segmented controller to retain the newly chosen segment, and I thought that was what the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method would do. Obviously my understanding is faulty here, but where?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue;
   popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;

   UIPopoverController *popoverController;
   popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
   popoverController.delegate = self;

   SettingsEditorViewController *editorVC;
   editorVC = (SettingsEditorViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;
   audioMessageChoiceIndex = editorVC.audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex;
   NSLog(@"audioMessageChoiceIndex = %d", audioMessageChoiceIndex);
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    NSInteger *newAudioMessageChoiceIndex = (NSInteger *)((SettingsEditorViewController *)                     
        popoverController.contentViewController).audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex;

    popoverController.delegate = self;    
    SettingsEditorViewController *editorVC;
    editorVC = (SettingsEditorViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;
    editorVC.audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex = *(newAudioMessageChoiceIndex);
}
```

Comment: Without it I kept getting a pointer to NSInteger type conversion error, so I decided to try typecasting it as an NSInteger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing here:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    NSInteger *newAudioMessageChoiceIndex = (NSInteger *)((SettingsEditorViewController *)                     
        popoverController.contentViewController).audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex;

    popoverController.delegate = self;    
    SettingsEditorViewController *editorVC;
    editorVC = (SettingsEditorViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;
    editorVC.audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex = *(newAudioMessageChoiceIndex);
}
```

I guess app crashes because you are trying to dereference small `NSInteger` as a pointer.

Rewriting:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    SettingsEditorViewController * editorVC = 
            (SettingsEditorViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;

    NSInteger newAudioMessageChoiceIndex = editorVC.audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex;

    editorVC.audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex = newAudioMessageChoiceIndex;
}
```

Are you trying to set `selectedSegmentIndex` with it's own value? And there was no point in setting popover's delegate in delegate method.

In case you wish to keep `UISegmentedControl` state between popover sessions, just keep it in caller' property and set `selectedSegmentIndex`before presenting:

```
@property NSInteger audioMessageChoiceIndex;

@synthesize audioMessageChoiceIndex;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   /* ... */
   SettingsEditorViewController *editorVC = (SettingsEditorViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;
   editorVC.audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex = self.audioMessageChoiceIndex;
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    SettingsEditorViewController * editorVC = 
            (SettingsEditorViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController;
    self.audioMessageChoiceIndex = editorVC.audioMessageChoice.selectedSegmentIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so very much for your suggestions! In order to get this to compile I had to insert the first five lines of my original code in the prepareForSegue method. As you surmised and suggested, I put the

Comment: I tried to do this, but the newly selected segment is not being retained and shown as selected for the next popover call. Can you please tell me how to do this?  I appreciate you patience here, as I am new at this iOS stuff and have a lot to learn.

Comment: Have you `@synthesize`d `audioMessageChoiceIndex` property?